# How to get a descriptive prediction instead of just getting predicted values with a confidence score?

Tags: python, time-series, data-analysis, large-language-model, predictive

Here's the context.
I have some time series data, with system utilisation info.
I can use ARIMA, LSTM, Etc, and get a set of predictions and calculate confidence score and so on.

But, I wish to get a descriptive understanding of the prediction..
Like.. "A is predicted to peak at time B, and this has been predicted by using C attribute, which has seen similar peaks at time D"
The above is just an example.

The final goal is to have a chatbot, which can take questions about the said system and provide prediction as a descriptive reply.

How do I get started with this?

I have tried researching about any LLMs that have the ability to analyse time series data, but I am unable to figure out how to integrate that for my requirement.

Comment: This is one of the issues in using ML. What you are hoping for is nearly impossible, as even the greatest ML researchers arent entirely sure how the machine gets to its predictions; all we know is whether the output is correct or not. 
The machine does not think like we do, so a response of “if A, then B” would not be what it gives you. Regardless, an LLM combined with your current model would be the closest solution that I can think of, although it would not be quite right.